# How to block mat-select via directive in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular-material, angular-directive

I am working with Angular 9 / typescript. I want to disable some of the form elements under a certain condition. I found such a [good example](https://medium.com/@imdurgeshpal/enable-disable-all-dom-elements-inside-div-in-angular-using-directive-56ca4602ab7b), where the author disables all elements. I edited his example. Everything is fine, but MAT-SELECT is not disabled and remains the only active element. Please tell me how to disable it?

[image]

Example from the article:

```
private disableElement(element: any) {
    if (this.appDisable) {
      if (!element.hasAttribute(DISABLED)) {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, APP_DISABLED, '');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, DISABLED, 'true');

        // disabling anchor tab keyboard event
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          this.renderer.setAttribute(element, TAB_INDEX, '-1');
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (element.hasAttribute(APP_DISABLED)) {
        if (element.getAttribute('disabled') !== '') {
          element.removeAttribute(DISABLED);
        }
        element.removeAttribute(APP_DISABLED);
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          element.removeAttribute(TAB_INDEX);
        }
      }
    }
    if (element.children) {
      for (let ele of element.children) {
        this.disableElement(ele);
      }
    }
  }
```

My code:

```
private disableElement(element: any) {
    if (this.appDisable) {
      if (element.tagName == "INPUT" || element.tagName == "MAT-SELECT" || element.tagName == "BUTTON") {
        if (!element.hasAttribute(DISABLED)) {
          this.renderer.setAttribute(element, APP_DISABLED, '');
          this.renderer.setAttribute(element, DISABLED, 'true');

          // disabling anchor tab keyboard event
          if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(element, TAB_INDEX, '-1');
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (element.tagName == "INPUT" || element.tagName == "MAT-SELECT" || element.tagName == "BUTTON") {
        if (element.hasAttribute(APP_DISABLED)) {
          if (element.getAttribute('disabled') !== '') {
            element.removeAttribute(DISABLED);
          }
          element.removeAttribute(APP_DISABLED);
          if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
            element.removeAttribute(TAB_INDEX);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (element.children) {
      for (let ele of element.children) {
        this.disableElement(ele);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a mat-select  is not a input select

If you are working with ReactiveForms you can create your own directive. that use `enable()` and `disable()` methods of FormControls

A directive like

```
import {Directive,Input,} from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroupDirective } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appDisable]"
})
export class DisableDirective {
  constructor(private fgd: FormGroupDirective) {}
  @Input() set appDisable(value: boolean) {
    Object.keys(this.fgd.form.controls).forEach(x => {
      const control = this.fgd.form.get(x);
      if (control) {
        if (value) control.disable();
        else control.enable();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can use in the form

```
<form [formGroup]="form" [appDisable]="disabled">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="food">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                {{food.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="name"/>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button mat-button (click)="disabled=!disabled">{{disabled?'Enable!':'Disable!'}}</button>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnvx3t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisabled.directive.ts)

**Update** how reach a button or how reach the NgControls
If we need reach a button or a NgControl, we need use ContentChild and ContenChildren. We can declare two variables

```
  @ContentChild(MatButton) button: MatButton;
  @ContentChildren(NgControl, { descendants: true }) controls: QueryList<NgControl>;
```

As to get a ContentChild we only can reach after ngAfterView init, translate the code in a setter to a function. Well, we change the function so, si we are not working with reactive Forms we disable the controls too.

```
  setEnabled(value: boolean) {
    if (this.fgd) { //we are using with a [formGroup]
      Object.keys(this.fgd.form.controls).forEach(x => {
        const control = this.fgd.form.get(x);
        if (control) {
          if (value) control.disable();
          else control.enable();
        }
      });
    } else { //we are not using Reactive Forms
      if (this.controls) {
        this.controls.forEach(x => {
          const control = x.ngControl;
          if (control) {
            if (value) control.disable();
            else control.enable();
          }
        });
      }
    }
    //to disabled/enabled the submitButton
    if (this.button) this.button.disabled = value;
  }
```

Well, we need call to the function in ngAfterViewInit and in the setter, and use a new private variable _disable

```
  @Input() set appDisable(value: boolean) {
    this._disable = value;
    this.setEnabled(value);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.setEnabled(this._disable);
  }
```

NOTE: The stackblitz are updated we all this changes

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have not used ReactiveForms yet (use template-driven forms). Maybe you know more options on how to do this? And tell me, please, how can I disable the button using ReactiveForms?

Comment: I update the answer, and use ContentChild and ContentChildren to "reach" the controls

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your code above would work for a normal select, not mat-select having a material  directive attached.

The element you are getting with the ViewChild is actually of the type MatSelect which doesn't have a property nativeElement. So what is undefined in your case is.

But can't you just use something like this: ?

In your template

```
  <mat-select [disabled]=isDisabled >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

and in your component you can set "isDisabled" to true or false under your certain conditions.

Comment: The fact is that I showed a screenshot of a simple component here, and I have components that use several child components. And it would be convenient for me to block all the components of the form that I need by simply applying the directive at the very top of the form. Otherwise, I will have to bind to the [disabled] property in each component

Comment: Yeah understandable, Eliseo's answer is perfect then ;)